# Can I use User Defined Exceptions in other programs (Like Class Library)?

Tags: c#, exception

This piece code works well, but if I want to use it in other programs, how can i do that?

Is it possible to create the exception like class library? If yes, how?

```
namespace Exception_CreatingUserDefined
{
    public class FirstOperandSmallException : Exception
    {
        public FirstOperandSmallException(String message) : base (message)
        {
        }       
    }

    public class operation
    {
        int op1, op2;

        public void operatn()
        {
            if(op1 < op2)
            {
                throw (new FirstOperandSmallException("First Operand Should not be Small"));
            }
            else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            operation opr = new operation();
            try
            {
                opr.operatn();
            }
            catch(FirstOperandSmallException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FirstOperandSmallException : {0}",e.Message);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can, use it as any other .NET built-in exception- reference the dll, adding `using namespace Exception_CreatingUserDefined`, and then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kenny said, by simply including your namespace you are able to use any public classes you have defined inside it. To accomplish this, please do the following:

- Make your exception class (and desired constructors) public.
- Change the output type of this assembly to the 'Library' type. To do this, right click your project and go to Properties and set the output type as Library.

Also, common practice with Class Libraries is to remove your `main` (entrance) code, so it only has classes and methods.

Comment: Add these steps to make the answer complete: 1. set Output Type = Class Library in project properties pane, 2. Mark FirstOperandSmallException as public.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask why you need to create a Exception like this in the first place.  You aren't adding any additional properties with your custom exception.  If it was me I would just throw InvalidOperationException and not create a custom exception.

I would only create a custom exception if you have additional data you need to get into your Exception or if you have code that needs to specifically catch that exception.  The framework has many built-in Exceptions you can use that cover a range of issues.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. As of now i don't need a custom Exception to be created. But i just wanted to know "how to". The example given here is just for telling the way i need to create a custom one.

Comment: You should read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx about how to create a custom exception.  For example your custom exception needs to be serializable.